# Trying to get inbound text responses in GoHighLevel

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-api

I have Twilio integrated with GoHighlevel. I am trying to get inbound SMS responses to appear in the GHL contact. Outbound messages are functioning and logging correctly, but not inbound. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I've not used GoHighLevel, so this is a bit of a stab in the dark.

Incoming messages to a Twilio number trigger a webhook (an HTTP request) to an application to notify the application. If the webhooks aren't set up correctly, then those messages won't make it to the other application (though they are all stored within Twilio).

I would recommend you log in to your Twilio account and check the settings for your numbers. You want to ensure that your numbers have a GoHighLevel URL setup for incoming messages.

In one of the [GoHighLevel support topic videos for Twilio](https://help.gohighlevel.com/support/solutions/articles/48000981421-import-existing-twilio-numbers-into-highlevel) I spotted what the webhook URL should probably look like.

```
https://api.gohighlevel.com/twilio/incoming_message
```

Check your numbers, make sure they have something like that. And if it is still not working then I would contact GoHighLevel support to find out what the correct settings should be.

Answer (score 0):

It was kinda hard to find their API docs, but I just found this:
https://highlevel.stoplight.io/docs/integrations/b7ada313a6066-inbound-message

According to their docs:

For listening to inbound messages
You need to change the Messaging webhook to -
https://services.msgsndr.com/conversations/providers/twilio/inbound_message

You can find it inside your Twilio Account -
Phone Numbers > Active Number > Click on the number > Messaging > A Message comes in

If you want to revert, here's the old messaging webhook url -

https://msgsndr.com/twilio/incoming_message